# Reducing the list of results (SQL)

Tags: sql, informix

I stuck on an SQL statement since 2 days now and I hope you can help me with that.

The result of my select is a list with 4 attributes A, B, C and D (below is an example list of 5 datasets):

```
 1. A=1 B=100 C=200 D=300
 2. A=2 B=200 C=100 D=300
 3. A=3 B=300 C=200 D=100
 4. A=3 B=100 C=100 D=200
 5. A=3 B=300 C=100 D=200
```

The list shall be reduced, so that every attribute `A` is in the list only once.

In the example above the dataset 1. and 2. should be in the list, because `A=1` and `A=2` exists only once.

For `A=3` I have to build a query to identify the dataset, that will be in the final list. Some rules should apply:

1. Take the dataset with the highest value of `B`; if not distinct then
2. Take the dataset with the highest value of `C`; if not distinct then
3. Take the dataset with the highest value of `D`.

In the example above the dataset 3. should be taken.

The expected result is:

```
1.A=1 B=100 C=200 D=300
2.A=2 B=200 C=100 D=300
3.A=3 B=300 C=200 D=100
```

I hope you understand my problem. I've tried various versions of `SELECT`-statements with `HAVING` and `EXISTS` (or `NOT EXISTS`), but my SQL knowledge isn't enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is an easier way to solve this problem, but this one works:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE TEST (
A INTEGER,
B INTEGER,
C INTEGER,
D INTEGER
);

insert into TEST values (1,1,1,1);
insert into TEST values (2,1,5,1);
insert into TEST values (2,2,1,1);
insert into TEST values (3,1,4,1);
insert into TEST values (3,2,1,4);
insert into TEST values (3,2,3,1);
insert into TEST values (3,3,1,5);
insert into TEST values (3,3,2,3);
insert into TEST values (3,3,2,7);
insert into TEST values (3,3,3,1);
insert into TEST values (3,3,3,2);

select distinct
t1.A,
t2.B as B,
t3.C as C,
t4.D as D
from TEST t1 
join (select A ,MAX (B) as B from TEST group by A)t2 on t2.A=t1.A
join (select A, B, MAX(C) as C from TEST group by A,B)t3 on t3.A=t2.A and t3.B=t2.B
join (select A, B, C, MAX (D) as D  from TEST group by A,B,C)t4 on t4.A=t3.A and t4.B=t3.B and t4.C=t3.C;
```

Result:

```
a   b   c   d
1   1   1   1
2   2   1   1
3   3   3   2
```

Tested on IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.10.FC3.

Answer (score 1):

This type of prioritization query is most easily done with `row_number()`, but I don't think Informix supports that.

So, one method is to enumerate the rows using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from t t2
              where (t2.b > t.b) or
                    (t2.b = t.b and t2.c > t.c) or
                    (t2.b = t.b and t2.c = t.c and t2.d > t.d)
             ) as NumGreater
      from t
     ) t
where NumGreater = 0;
```

Comment: I really like this approach, but it doesn't replicate the partition by functionality of row_number().  If I'm reading it correctly, you won't see a returned record where A = 1 or 2.

Comment: thanks i learned something new in this answer 
to add the result of 1 and 2 you have to add t2.a=t.a in the subquery of NumGreater

Comment: Would you care to show a ROW_NUMBER() solution?  Informix supports most of the OLAP-ish SQL in the latest versions — and [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2591.htm) specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about `Informix` but you can try. This works in `Sql Server`. May be it will also work in `Informix`:

```
select * from tablename t1
where id = (select first 1 id from tablename t2 
            where t2.A = t1.A order by B desc, C desc, D desc)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT A, MAX(B) AS B, MAX(C) AS C, MAX(D) AS D
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY A
```

Comment: This will not work. This will return `A=3 B=300 C=200 D=200` but he wants `A=3 B=300 C=200 D=100`

Comment: But he wrote "3. Take the dataset with the highest value of D" in the above

Comment: But that's not what your statement does. Your statement takes the highest value for each column, not all columns from the row with the highest value in the column `D`